# How can I install a Synaptics pointing driver?

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, the latest version available from the Ubuntu website

When I'm using windows 8, the touch pad works well with the installed synaptics pointing driver, handling all features like horizontal, vertical scroll as well as circle scrolling etc.

But the problem is, In Ubuntu I only get vertical scrolling. Can anyone tell me how to install synaptics pointing driver for all such functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The way I corrected it was to install **Synaptiks** from the Ubuntu Software Center.
[image: Synaptiks]

This gave me all the options which you are looking for.

Comment: In "Ubuntu Software" searching for Synaptics doesnt show touchpad software

Answer (score 2):

If the touchpad is detected correctly, the synaptics driver shold be autoloaded. Check it with the following command:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i synaptics
```

A positive output would look something like this:

```
~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep synaptics
[    32.848] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    32.849] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    33.096] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.097] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[    33.097] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    33.160] (II) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: ignoring touch events for semi-multitouch device
[    33.160] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 1152
[    33.160] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 768
[    33.160] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255
[    33.160] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 0 - 15
[    33.160] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left right double triple
[    33.160] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
[    33.161] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[    33.189] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    33.190] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    33.190] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: AccelFactor is now 0.145
[    33.192] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[ 18442.841] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
```

If that's what you get, try turning on horizontal scrolling with

```
synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1
```

Comment: what if my log does not have synaptics in it? Ask the related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954565/enabling-mouse-pad-pinch-zoom-on-ubuntu-17)