# Touch-pad swipe guestures

Tags: touchpad

Is there any way to get the 2 finger swipe to scroll gesture in Ubuntu? It was present in Windows 8.1 before I switched to Ubuntu. I am using the new Lenove Ideapad Z510 laptop.

Comment: You mean you need the two-finger scroll right? It is present in **System settings -> Mouse and Touchpad** and then enable "Two finger scroll".

Comment: @Jobin Yeah. I tried that now. I don't have that option at all. I just have **Primary button** and **double click** under **general** and **pointer speed** under **mouse**. Is it because i haven't installed the required drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which Ubuntu version you use, so here are some links that may be useful:

- [How can I install a Synaptics pointing driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337049/how-can-i-install-a-synaptics-pointing-driver)
- [SynapticsTouchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)
- [How to install Synaptics on touchpad on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453876/how-to-install-synaptiks-on-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 missing Synaptics Touchpad Utility](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217808)

Try to read through these, I hope it'll help you :)

Comment: I am using latest Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/373134/277426) solution and also go through the last two links provided above. have a nice day :)