# Enabling zoom in and out gesture on touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I used zoom in and zoom out with single finger vertically on left side of touchpad in windows. Its particularly useful during browsing as it enlarges text in browser. But unfortunately we cant configure touchpad properties in ubuntu. So can I enable vertical single finger slide on left side of touchpad for zoom in and zoom out. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I honestly do not know but, until someone comes along to help you that does know, I can offer you a fairly simply work-around that is pretty universal.

My solution has been to simply use the 'Ctrl' and the '+' or '-' keys. This is pretty universal and I have just checked in Opera, Firefox, and Chromium. In all three cases, depressing the 'CTRL' Key and pressing the '+' key increases the text size and the '-' key decreases the text size and the image size.

Until someone comes along with a better answer there's that option and it may serve your needs.

You have indicated that you're using the Alps touchpad. As such, I'd suggest taking a look at this page:
[Installing ALPS Multitouch drivers in LINUX | ayushyajaiswal.blogspot.com](http://ayushyajaiswal.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-alps-multitouch-drivers-in.html)

Comment: If you know who makes the touchpad, they're usually made by a third party, you *may* be able to find special drivers and a configuration applet to install at their site. This is for Mint but you may want to take a look here: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1361 Also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337049/how-can-i-install-a-synaptics-pointing-driver - I forgot to add that.

Comment: Thanks a lot KGIII.... In windows it says Alps touchpad driver.. So the company probably is Alps... Also mint referral site has query with horizontal scrolling but my horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling are perfect... In Ubuntu referral site it days to install Synaptiks... But when I search for it in software center it says no matches found... Please let me know if you have any links related to Alps touchpad drivers for Ubuntu... Your help is truly appreciated...

Comment: I edited the post to include a link to a site that may help you - it looks well written and gives a couple of different options. Personally, I don't use the stuff and just use the CTRL key. But, the link has been added. Here it is again. http://ayushyajaiswal.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-alps-multitouch-drivers-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Hold the key `CTRL` and move 2 fingers on your touchpad to the top or to the bottom. Like if you were scrolling using your touchpad.